# Is invoke-direct really invoking the methods that are defined in the instantiated object?

Tags: android, dalvik, smali

I have some test code, which is a `ConcreteClass` inheriting the `AbstractClassForInterface1`. 
In the generated smali code for the constructor of `ConcreteClass`:

```
# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 4
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lorg/ucomb/AbstractClassForInterface1;-><init>()V 

    return-void
.end method
```

`p0` is actually the instantiated object of type `ConcreteClass`, since it's from the instantiation:

```
new-instance v0, Lorg/ucomb/ConcreteClass1;

invoke-direct {v0}, Lorg/ucomb/ConcreteClass1;-><init>()V
```

and it is easy to understand that the object `v0` has the method `Lorg/ucomb/ConcreteClass1;-><init>()V`,

Then in the body, why using `invoke-direct` on the `p0` to invoke the super class's constructor like this:

`invoke-direct {p0}, Lorg/ucomb/AbstractClassForInterface1;-><init>()V`
?

Isn't the `invoke-direct` supposed to invoke method without virtual method resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a direct method, the exact method that is being called is specified. In this case, `Lorg/ucomb/AbstractClassForInterface1;-><init>()V`. This is not a virtual table lookup - it is guaranteed to be the `AbstractClassForInterface1` constructor. If it were a virtual table lookup, it would resolve to the most specialized override of the `<init>()V` method, which would be the `<init>()V` method in your ConcreteClass1 class.

Comment: So you mean, * syntactically * from the method path in `invoke-direct` instruction, like `invoke-direct {p0}, Lorg/ucomb/AbstractClassForInterface1;-><init>()V`, we will know that the class of the invoked object should be `Lorg/ucomb/AbstractClassForInterface1`, and there is the `<init>` method define in the class?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.